# How to pass data from one UIView to another UIView with using only one ViewController in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm creating a simple login form where the username from textfield should show up in the other UIView when clicking the Login button.

How do I pass data from textfield of a UIViewA and display the value from textfield to a label in UIViewB?

There's only 1 ViewController where the UIViews will interchanged so there's no segue needed.

here is the button function from the login UIView:

```
class UIView1: UIView {
        @IBAction func buttontohome(_ sender: Any) {
            if (usernamebox.text == username || usernamebox.text == email) && passwordbox.text == password
            {
               // load UIView2 and send username string to UIView2 label
            }
            else {
                loadViewFromNib()
                loginfaillabel.text = "Login failed"
            }

        }
        }
```

Here's the second UIView where the username string should appear once the login is succeed:

```
 class UIView2: UIView {

       @IBOutlet var labelforpassedvalue: UILabel!

        var usernamelabel = String()

func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
             labelforpassedvalue.text = "Welcome Bob, " + usernamelabel

    }
}
```

Please help...

Comment: This sounds like a broken design, why are there no ViewControllers present? Are you sure you want to keep it having two or more views in one parentview with the views communicating to each other directly?

Comment: I currently have 2 ViewControllers for each UIView but I'm wondering if it's possible to render 2 UIView Interchangeably by only using one ViewController. Is it possible to pass data from UIView1 to UIView2 if the the login button is placed within UIView1 instead of ViewController?

Comment: I currently don't have any functions in my ViewController.swift. If I should, what function should I add in there in order to make it work for passing data between two UIViews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with [luk2302](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302); this is flawed design and you may want to rethink the way you're going about this.

That said, if you *have* to go about it this way, one approach would be to declare an optional in your main ViewController like so:

```
var usernameLabelText: String?
```

and then update its value when the `buttontohome` action is called:

```
usernameLabelText = usernamebox.text
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to replace the old UIView with the new one.

Comment: Thank you. One more question though, is it possible to identify and manipulate the variables of a UIView class in ViewController class? All I need is to make the ViewController recognize the text typed in a textfield of UIView and pass it to the next UIView.

Comment: Yes it is possible to manipulate a UIView's variables in a ViewController, as long as you have a reference to the UIView in the ViewController. Again, though, this isn't the best way to go about it. I would recommend a cursory read of https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html 
to get a better idea of how to pass data around. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I'll try to read it. I'm fairly new in iOS development and honestly I don't know where to start. Any reference would help a lot! Thanks sir.